# AngularJs - Close modal from Controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a modal which i am trying to close from the controller - however i am unable to do so

```
<button type="button" class="add-entry-btn-group" data-animation="am-fade-    and-slide-top" data-template-url="states/../numbersModal.html" bs-    modal="modal">New</button>
```

Modal HTML ->
numbersModal.html -

```
<div class="modal" id="addNumbersModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"     data-backdrop="static" aria-labelledby="addNumbersModal"
     data-animation="am-fade-and-scale" data-placement="center" >
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form method="POST" class="form-horizontal group-border-dashed" name="addNumbersForm" novalidate>
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span>&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title"> ID Numbers</h4>
        </div>
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="closeIdNumbersModal()">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Close</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" type="reset" ng-click="idNumbers.closeIdNumbersModal()" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" ng-click="idNumbers.saveIdNumbers()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
```

Controller ->

```
function closeIdNumbersModal() {
//tried all these things - none works

    vm.addIdNumbersModal.$promise.then(vm.addIdNumbersModal.hide);
    vm.addIdNumbersModal.close;
    vm.addIdNumbersModal.hide;
    vm.addIdNumbersModal.hide;
}
```

Comment: Can you please create a plunkr or jsbin?
What are you using for modal? Angular UI Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

These look like [Bootstrap modal classes](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

If so, then you can close them using JQuery (which is a dependency of bootstrap.js):

```
$('#addNumbersModal').modal('hide');
```